# MySQL return all rows where a value exists in a column

Tags: php, mysql

Quick question, probably very simple.  Let's say I've got a table in a database.

```
PID | Column1 
 1  |   A
 2  |   B
 3  |   C
 4  |   A
 5  |   A
 6  |   B
```

How would I return every PID associated with, say, the appearance of "A" in Column1?

```
$aInColumn1 = {1,4,5};
```

...or something like that.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `$array[] = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM NameOfTheTable WHERE Column1 = A");` where NameOfTheTable is name of the table of this columns.

Comment: If you want it returned in array, make sure you use `$array[] = `

Comment: @overallduka `mysqli_query`*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select PID from tableName where Column1 = 'A'
```